# Iterating over a iterable containg lists

Tags: python

I would have expected the following:

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
for i in a:
    i = "x"
print(a)
```

to give:

```
["x","x","x"]
```

but `a` actually remains unchanged. Why is this? I would have thought that `i` was simply a pointer to an array. What is `i`? Surely its not a copy of [1] with regard to the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I'm afraid your assumption is incorrect, `i` is in fact a copy. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
for i in range(0, len(a)-1):
    a[i] = 'X'
print(a)
```

The reason for this is because you're "picking out" a copy of each object in your array as a stand-alone item referred as `i` in your loop.

```
a = [[1],[2],[3]]
for copiedItem in a:
    copiedItem = 'x' # Replaces your copy that you just picked out from a.
```

Meaning you're replacing your copy of the item, not the actual item in your array/list. You need to replace by indexing `a[<index>]` in order to replace items in your list.

Another example would be this:

```
a = ['moo', 'cow', 'cat']
myCopy = a[0] # Copies 'moo' into 'myCopy'
myCopy = 'THE DEVIL' # Replaces 'moo'.. over your copy..

print(a)
['moo', 'cow', 'cat']

print(myCopy)
'THE DEVIL'
```

Might be a bad example, but it basically does the same thing except that your for loop is a iterating generator of the list object that returns each item as a asynchronous `return` called `yield`. Each returned item is simply a copy and not a reference to the initial object thus being the same thing as just copying `a[0]` :)

Comment: As a more pythonic way you can use `enumerate`!

Comment: @Kasra correct, however since that's a helper function that basically does the same. I kept it clean and simple for learning purposes. Since you replace items in a list by accessing it via indexes, and enumerate gives you more data than you need (it gives you both index and the value) you're better of just doing it this way to learn how indexes works. But you got a valid point never the less.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about Python in terms of pointers can be misleading. Instead, you need to learn to think in terms of objects being bound to names.

So

```
for i in a:
```

successively binds the name `i` to each of the objects in the iterable object `a`, which in this case are single element lists.

Then

```
    i = "x"
```

binds the literal string object `"x"` to the name `i`, which over-rides the previous binding, so it has no effect on `a` or its contents.

Note that

```
>>> for i in a:
...     i[0] = "x"
... 
>>> print a
[['x'], ['x'], ['x']]
```

does do what you (probably) expect, since `i[0] = "x"` is modifying the list that's currently bound to `i`, it's not binding a new object to `i`.

An excellent guide to this topic is SO member Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).